# When $ac \gt bd$ is true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose $a \gt b$ and $c \gt d$ . What's the conditions for $a$ , $b$ , $c $ and $d$ for which  $ac \gt bd$ being true ? Also how we can prove it ?

I tried many positive numbers and it was true but I don't know how prove it .

Comment: Note that the strongest thing of this kind you can always say is what you get from $a-b\gt0, c-d\gt 0$ which means $(a-b)(c-d)\gt 0$ or $ac+bd\gt ad+bc$. But this is weaker than the original because it is true whenever $a-b$ and $c-d$ have the same sign (they could both be negative as well as both positive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the numbers are positive, then:

- Since $a>b$, and $c>0$, you have $ac>bc$
- Since $c>d$, and $b>0$, you have $bc>bd$

Putting the two inequalities together gives you $ac>bd$.

Comment: And how we can prove first statement ?

Comment: @S.H.W which "first statement"?

Comment: @S.H.W If you mean $a>b, c>0\implies ac > bc$, that statement is an axiom.

Comment: Okay , Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2):

No, it's wrong.

Try $a=5$, $b=-6$, $c=2$ and $d=-3$.

For positives $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ it's true because
$$ac-bd=ac-bc+bc-bd=c(a-b)+b(c-d)>0$$

Comment: What about when $a , b , c , d$ are positive ?

Comment: @S.H.W I added something. See now please.

Comment: If you want prove $c(a-b) + b(c-d) \gt 0$ you should use the expression that I wrote again !

Comment: @S.H.W Since $a>b$  and $c>d$, we have $a-b>0$ and $c-d>0$. I used your expressions exactly.

Comment: Yes , you're right . Thanks !

Comment: @S.H.W You are welcome! Good luck!